# Custom JDialog - Find out if OK was presed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane, jdialog

I have a custom JDialog that I made in order to solve some local problems (RTL etc')
until now, it only had an "ok" option, 
I have to modify it now to also have a cancel button.
I did that.
the only problem now is that **I don't know how to get the input from it, was OK pressed or Cancel ?**

please help.

**this is my code:**

```
public MyDialog(String title,boolean withCancelButton) {

String message = "<html><b><font color=\"#8F0000\" size=\"7\" face=\"Ariel\">" + title + "</font></p></html>";

JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);        

JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, title);

dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();

if (pane.getOptionType() == 1)
    okWasPressed = true;
else
    okWasPressed = false;
```

}

**the thing is that pane.getOptionType() always return "2", so its probably the options count or something.**

**how can I get to the actual selection ?**

thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to use the standard functionality, like this:

```
int opt = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(jf, "Do you really want to?", "Confirm",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
if(opt == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Ok then!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Didn't think so.");
}
```

If you really want to use your own dialog, as in the example, you should use getValue() to check what was pressed:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Do you really want to?",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(jf, "Confirm");

dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();

int opt = (int) optionPane.getValue();
if(opt == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Ok then!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Didn't think so.");
}
```

Comment: Of course, this is a minimal example - you need to do a null check on the getValue() return too.

Comment: 10x - it did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it can be done like this:

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, "message", "title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask described in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)...

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.show();
 Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
 if(selectedValue == null)
   return CLOSED_OPTION;
 //If there is not an array of option buttons:
 if(options == null) {
   if(selectedValue instanceof Integer)
      return ((Integer)selectedValue).intValue();
   return CLOSED_OPTION;
 }
 //If there is an array of option buttons:
 for(int counter = 0, maxCounter = options.length;
    counter < maxCounter; counter++) {
    if(options[counter].equals(selectedValue))
    return counter;
 }
 return CLOSED_OPTION;
```

You should be able to use [`JOptionPane#getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#getValue())

However, unless you some massively pressing reason to do so, you should use one of the `static` factory methods.  See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details